# What can be done to make a perfect paraphrase?

Tags: python, python-3.x

With reference from the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3592020/4948889, I have tried to modify the example as below. The Google API in the answer in above link is not working for me.So I modify the example as given below:

```
import sys
import json
import goslate

def translate(text,lang1,lang2):

    gs = goslate.Goslate()
    content= gs.translate(text, lang2)
    try:
        trans_dict=json.loads(content)
    except AttributeError:
        try:
            trans_dict=json.load(content)    
        except AttributeError:
            trans_dict=json.read(content)
    return trans_dict['responseData']['translatedText']

languages='de da nl zh-tw ko es pt el'.split()
# text=(' '.join(sys.argv[1:])).decode('utf-8')
text = "Hi, We have a requirement in which we need to change the words or phrases in the sentence while keeping its meaning intact."

for lang in languages:
    result=translate(text,'en',lang)
    result=translate(result,lang,'en')
    print(result)
    print
```

After running the program, I am getting the follwoing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\testrephrase.py", line 25, in <module>
    result=translate(text,'en',lang)
  File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\testrephrase.py", line 10, in translate
    content= gs.translate(text, lang2)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\goslate.py", line 409, in translate
    return _unwrapper_single_element(self._translate_single_text(text, target_language, source_language))
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\goslate.py", line 334, in _translate_single_text
    results = list(self._execute(make_task(i) for i in split_text(text)))
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\goslate.py", line 203, in _execute
    yield each()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\goslate.py", line 332, in <lambda>
    return lambda: self._basic_translate(text, target_language, source_lauguage)[0]
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\goslate.py", line 251, in _basic_translate
    response_content = self._open_url(url)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\goslate.py", line 191, in _open_url
    raise e
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\goslate.py", line 181, in _open_url
    response = self._opener.open(request, timeout=self._TIMEOUT)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

I do not what to do so tat my code run efficiently and create the paraphrases without changing the meaning of the sentence.

I am using Python 3.6 and Windows 10 as OS.
Kindly, help me.

Answer (score 2):

The following [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/goslate) shows the following:

> Google has updated its translation service recently with a ticket
>   mechanism to prevent simple crawler program like goslate from
>   accessing. Though a more sophisticated crawler may still work
>   technically, however it would have crossed the fine line between using
>   the service and breaking the service. goslate will not be updated to
>   break google’s ticket mechanism. Free lunch is over. Thanks for using.

So the library I do not currently work, consequently the example is useless.

Comment: So is there no solution so that the program works and I can get paraphrases? Please advise. If you have any other solution please suggest me.

Comment: With this library you will not be able to do it, you could look for another library